# Error: Could not start the command: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file".tex

Tags: installing

I have not used Latex for a while but now want to use it again. Unfortunately I can't remember how to set up Latex. The first thing I did was to open an earlier .tex-file. When compiling I get this message:

```
Error: Could not start the command: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "filename".tex
```

I wonder what I forgot to do?

I am running TexStudio with TexLive on a Linux Mint 20 machine.

TexStudio and Texlive both seem to be successfully installed.
Yet, running

```
xelatex -version
```

returns

```
bash: xelatex: command not found
```

UPDATE: I found a (6 years) old suggestion to install not "texlive" but "texlive-xetex" (https://makandracards.com/makandra/29089-how-to-install-the-xelatex-binary-on-ubuntu-14-04)

It solved the problem

Comment: That usually means that you have not installed tex (ie miktex or texlive) but it could be that it is installed but your editor is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have installed texlive, but I did not restart the computer afterwards. Perhaps that will be necessary in order for texstudio to find the relevant place of texlive? I will try that.

Comment: A restart did not help. In fact I now get the same message twice!

Comment: you have not given any information that would allow anyone to help. first check it works on the commandline, what happens if you type `xelatex -version` ? If that works then it is your editor that is wrong in whch case show where you have installed xetex and what your editor config looks like

Comment: Are you also 100% sure the installation went well? TeXLive ends up with a message with a "Welcome to TeXLive". Additionally what OS are you using? It is not obvious from your question. On Windows this should work. On Linux there are a number of things one could do wrong. So please update your question with this information

Comment: From running 'xelatex --verison' it seems that xelatex is not installed. But isn't xelatex inclkuded in TexLive? The ælatest version of TexLive is installed. I have added information about my OS, i.e. Linux Mint 20.

Comment: SOLVED: I found a (6 years) old suggestion to install not "texlive" but "texlive-xetex" (https://makandracards.com/makandra/29089-how-to-install-the-xelatex-binary-on-ubuntu-14-04)

It solved the problem

Comment: I now recall, that I used to install `texlive-full`. That would (probably) have solved the problem. Thanks for your comments and patience.

Comment: And now you know why such information (about OS etc) is important to have in the original question.